# Como sumar dos campos TIME y almacenar el resultado en un distinto

Tags: sql-server

Tengo tres campos en SQL SERVER:

```sql
Hora_Inicio TIME,
Hora_Final TIME,
Total_Horas_Trabajadas TIME,
```

Como puedo sumar los dos primeros campos y almacenar el resultado en el 3ro? Llevo mucho buscando esa información y aun no he encontrado una consulta que me funcione.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Comment: Muestranos el codigo de la composicion de tu tabla o como estas haciendo tu consulta sql

Comment: ASI ESTA LA CONSULTA                                                  
                                                                                                                              
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF (Hora_Inicio,Hora_Final)))
  ) total FROM Servicios_DN;

:(

Comment: Quisiera almacenar el resultado en la ultimo campo llamdo Total_Horas_Trabajadas, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF('Hora_Inicio', 'Hora_Fina') as total FROM Servicios_DN;
 prueba eso a ver

Comment: Ya lo intente, muchisimas gracias <3 pero dice que esa funcion requiere de tres argumentos :(

Comment: Lo intentaste desde la base de datos? Me parece que ese error no tiene relacion con sql

Comment: Si lo intente desde ahi

Comment: Encontré esto SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `hora_inicio`, `hora_fin`) AS total FROM `Servicios_DN;`

Answer (score 1):

Es importante poner la definición de lo que tienes y lo que esperas obtener, porque la resolución puede ser muy diferente.

```
Declare @tiempos table (TiempoInicio time(0), tiempoFinal time (0))
Insert into @tiempos(TiempoInicio, tiempoFinal)
values 
  ('00:15','11:15'),
  ('08:15','15:45'),
  ('10:00','18:33'),
  ('12:31','23:11'),
  ('00:15','11:15');

select TiempoInicio, tiempoFinal, 
    datediff(minute,tiempoinicio, tiempoFinal)/60 as horas, 
    datediff(minute,tiempoinicio, tiempoFinal)%60 as minutos,
    TIMEFROMPARTS((datediff(minute,tiempoinicio, tiempoFinal)/60)
        ,(datediff(minute,tiempoinicio, tiempoFinal)%60)
        ,0
        ,0
        ,0) as result
from @tiempos;
```

[image: Result]

Con la función `dateDiff`, puedes ir calculando las diferencias en unidades de tiempo entre la columna de inicio y la de final.

Una vez tienes claro el resultado a obtener, puedes utilizar por ejemplo la función `timeFromParts`, y establecer cada uno de los 5 parámetros que requiere entre las unidades de tiempo que precises.

[DateDiff](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)